# JNI Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Is there any kind of plugin that performs the task of writing a JNI-Wrapper around an existing C++ DLL?

Thanks!

Stefan

Comment: Shame that there doesn't seem to be one. It certainly would improve productivity. I guess the market size isn't big enough :(

Answer (score 1):

It isn't an Eclipse plugin, but you could take a look at [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html).

From the documentation:

> The Java extension to SWIG makes it very easy to plumb in existing C/C++ code for access from Java, as SWIG writes the Java Native Interface (JNI) code for you.